# How can I format django form values before and after submitting

Tags: python, django, django-forms

My application deals with logging time. In the model it stores periods of time as integer minutes. On the front end I'd like users to be able to enter times as integer minutes, decimal hours (e.g 1.5 = 90 mins) or hours and minutes (e.g. 01:30 = 90 mins). I'd also like the form to show the field values in the user's preferred format (which they can set in a profile module).

I have set up a template filter which takes the user's preference and displays the appropriate format for each entry on display pages (sent in the context and fed through a template tag formatter), but I'd like to do the same on forms - i.e. display the form value in the appropriate format and allow the user to enter a time in any of the three different formats.

Here is a rough outline of what I have, this model allows users to set a start state for various fields in the system:

models.py:

```
class PreviousHours(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    logged_minutes_1 = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    logged_minutes_2 = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    logged_minutes_3 = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    ...
```

forms.py:

```
class PreviousHoursForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PreviousHours
        exclude = ('user')
```

To convert integer minutes to the appropriate format I have a `format_minutes` method which calls `minutes_to_decimal_hours` or `minutes_to_hhmm` as appropriate. These return the appropriately formatted time, or if minutes = 0, the empty string. I also have methods which take a string, checking it's format with a regular expression and return the minutes as an integer, throwing an exception if the format is wrong.

I have manually created my form layout in a template as it is fairly specific, so I am currently using `{{ form.logged_minutes_1 }}` style entries to render the input boxes as appropriate.

Do I need to create a new form widget to do this? Or is there another method? I'm not entirely sure on the best approach.

Comment: I guess you'll be better off using datetimes and timedeltas, you can format this scructures whatever you like as in [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date) and you can even "humanize" the output [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/humanize/#naturaltime)

Comment: The main part of the app does indeed use datetimes and timedeltas to do calculations, but this section is purely to set up an initial state for each logged time field. Regardless of the storage type in the backend though, I'd still like to work out how to accept multiple formats of user input and translate to the backend format and vice-versa.